# Show power set union identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show if $a \in X$ then $P(a) \in P(P(\cup X))$

I define $P(a)= \left\{a:a \subseteq X\right\} $

I also have the identity $P(S) \cup P(T) \subseteq P(S\cup T)$, but I'm not sure how to start the problem.

I dont know where to start with this problem, any pointers as to where to look to be able to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your definition of $P(a)$ should be $\{b:b\subseteq a\}$. In fact you are defining $P(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $a\in X\Rightarrow a\subseteq\cup X$.
- Proving that $\wp\left(a\right)\in\wp\left(\wp\left(\cup X\right)\right)$
  comes to the same as proving that $\wp\left(a\right)\subseteq\wp\left(\cup X\right)$
  wich is a direct consequence of $a\subseteq\cup X$.